# $.each en peticion con ajax desde controlador php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hola estoy comezando a trabajar con ajax y php tengo un problema estoy realizando una peticion ajax, pediante post de un controlador php y estoi retornando en formato json el resultado desde el controlador.. los datos que necesito llegan perfecto ya realize las prueba. en mi condicion if,  si existe la igual, me tiene que direccionar caso contrario un alert.. mi problema es que en caso que no es igual va bien me muestra el alert, pero cuando es verdaderoo me muestra el alert y me direcciona, estoy haciendo algo mal en el $.each???

```html
$('#klik').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>home/validar',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

               $.each(data, function(i,item){
                  if (item.Url === 'ventas/index'){

                       window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sis_empresa/ventas';
                  }
               });
               alert('no tiene permisos');
              
            } 
        });       
      });
```

Comment: No entiendo por que recorres el objeto 'data' de esa manera. Puedes mostrar el contenido del objeto data?. Estas intentando comprobar que si almenos alguno de los items que estan dentro de 'data' es igual a  'ventas/index' entonces redireccione y si no que muestre la alerta?

Comment: Efectivamente eso es lo que deseo él objeto dará me devuelve en formato json un conjunto de datos

Answer (score 0):

> ¿estoy haciendo algo mal en el `$.each`?

No, tu problema es simplemente porque no usas condicionales para saber si tomar `x` o `y` acción.

```
let mustRedirect = false;
$.each(data, function(i,item){
  if (item.Url === 'ventas/index'){
    mustRedirect = true;
  }
});

if (mustRedirect) {
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost/sis_empresa/ventas';
} else {
  alert('no tiene permisos');
}
```